# Why is my udev rule not working?

Tags: bash, scripts, udev, raspberrypi

I need to automatically run my script `/var/www/html/configWWW` when any USB is plugged in to my Rasperry.

UDEV RULE - `/etc/udev/rules.d/myRule.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="****",
ATTR{idProduct}=="****", RUN+="/var/www/html/configWWW"
```

MY SCRIPT `/var/www/html/configWWW`

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/media/pi/`ls /media/pi`/SymSif.xml"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
        (
        echo "it works: $(date)" >> /home/pi/Desktop/test.txt
        )
else
        (
        echo "it does not works: $(date)" >> /home/pi/Desktop/test.txt
        )
fi
```

On the other hand, if i run script from bash `bash /var/www/html/configWWW`, it works!

Why doesn't my udev rule work like my bash command?

Comment: Did you `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` reload

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Another point is  that you have to use `ATTRS` instead of `ATTR` in the udev-rule.

Comment: Of course I used udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger, after every modification. And what is more, I changed file="/media/pi/ls /media/pi/SymSif.xml" to file="/media/pi/USB/SymSif.xml". And finally I changed ATTRS instead of ATTR, but It still does not work.  But still is the same status. If I run script from bash bash /var/www/html/configWWW, it works!

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem running scripts from udev, very little survives when the sandbox is discarded (mounts, network connections ...). The second reason, scripts running from udev will block all further events for this or a dependent device and will eventually timeout and all running processes started by the script will be unconditionally terminated.

You can get the same result by using systemd:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/garmin.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Autorun actions for Garmin FR620
Requires=dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGarmin_FR620_Flash\x2d0:0.device
After=dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGarmin_FR620_Flash\x2d0:0.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/autorun_garmin_fr620.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dGarmin_FR620_Flash\x2d0:0.device
```

<sup>You can find your .device unit by connecting your device and run `systemctl --all list-units`</sup>

don´t forget to enable your .service:

```
$ systemctl enable garmin.service
```

Or you could start your systemd .service from the udev rule:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-garmin-autorun.rules
```

```
# Start garmin FR620 systemd .service
ACTION=="add", \
KERNELS=="3-3", \
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", \
ATTRS{idProduct}=="2657", \
ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", \
TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="garmin.service"
```

...and the systemd .service could look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autorun actions for Garmin FR620

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/bin/autorun_garmin_fr620.sh
```

Comment: Wow.  I had been fighting udev for a long time trying to get it to automatically move/rename photos from my field cam using exiftool.  Using systemd instead just works!

Answer (score 1):

Better if you could add `udevadm info -a ...` to the post. Anyway, here few things I expect:

- Set the script executable permission bit.
- Change the rule filename to standard format, example `99-alpha.rules`
- Check out the difference between `SUBSYSTEM` and `SUBSYSTEMS`, and between `ATTR` and `ATTRS`.

See `man udev`

Comment: I don't think having a number in the name matters: `Files in there are parsed in alpha order, as long as the name ends with ".rules".` -[debian wiki: udev](https://wiki.debian.org/udev)

Comment: @Keith I wouldn't trust such online resumed documentation versus original/upstream one.  `man udev` has it clear `All rules files are collectively sorted and processed in *lexical order*, regardless of the directories in which they live. However, files with identical filenames replace each other. Files in /etc have the highest priority, files in /run take precedence over files with the same name in /lib.` . You can also verify it using `udevadm test ...` like in this question https://askubuntu.com/q/1144508/26246 . You are right about this case, `myRule.rules` is ordered last anyway.

Comment: I think I see.  You're saying that having a number in the filename isn't a requirement, just a recommendation, but that since most rules have a number, any of them could override your rule because the numbered rules will be processed first.

Comment: @Keith, Number is a recommendation to control when to run your rules within a chain of other rules. "override" in udev has multiple direction (a rule can affect previous and next rules). Examples: (1) Last rule can override actions from previous rules. (2) First rule can override environment variables, tags that may affect next rules decisions/conditions.